# Windows 8 UI: how can I handle right clicks?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I am making a small program for Windows 8, and I would like to let users with mouses the opportunity to right-click elements of a `GridView`.

While GridViews have the `ItemClick` event, these don't convey mouse buttons. They have a `RightTapped` (what does that even mean?) event, but it doesn't convey the clicked item, just the event source.

How can I tell which model object was right-clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't think for very long before asking this question. The target object can be accessed through `event.OriginalSource.DataContext` (once every bit in it has been casted to the appropriate class).

Extra care must be taken because right-clicking in the margins between grid elements still triggers the event, but on the GridView itself.